# Delete checkboxes in the active row and delete the entire row

Tags: excel, vba, checkbox

I originally wanted a simple macro to delete the entire row. I created this and soon found out it didn't delete the checkboxes. I tried to improvise and create a new macro that deleted all checkboxes in the active row and then deleted the row.

Unfortunately I was only able to delete checkboxes in the active cell and not the active row.

```
Sub DeleteCheckboxandRow()

Dim cb As CheckBox

For Each cb In ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes
    If cb.TopLeftCell.Address = ActiveCell.Address Then cb.Delete
Next
Rows(ActiveCell.Row).EntireRow.Delete
End Sub
```

Is someone able to explain how I can modify the above macro to delete the checkboxes from the whole active row not just the active cell?

Comment: My understanding is that you want to delete all `CheckBoxes` in the `ActiveSheet` and also delete the rows they are placed at.  Would you please confirm if the above is correct...

Comment: Have you tried the answer provided?

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub DeleteCheckboxandRow()

Dim cb As CheckBox

For Each cb In ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes
    If cb.TopLeftCell.Row = ActiveCell.Row Then cb.Delete
Next
ActiveCell.EntireRow.Delete
End Sub
```

Comment: I think you should provide a small explanation to your answer.

Comment: @JRodDynamite First, you loop over all CheckBoxes in ActiveSheet. The checkbox element has some margins. Depending on which cell the top left margin of the checkbox element is situated, you take the respective Row and check if it corresponds to the active Row. If it does, you delete the checkbox.
Second, you delete the entire Row where the Active cell is.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding of the requirements is:

- Need to delete all CheckBoxes in the ActiveSheet and also to delete the `Rows` where the `CheckBoxes` are placed.

Let’s first look into the `Placement` property of the `DrawingObjects` or `Shapes`. This property (see [Shape Members (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff193908.aspx):

> **Shape.Placement Property (Excel)**
>   Returns or sets an XlPlacement value that represents the way the
>   object is attached to the cells below it.

XlPlacement enumeration has this possible values:

> **Name: Description**
>
> xlFreeFloating: Object is free floating.
>
> xlMove: Object is moved with the cells.
>
> xlMoveAndSize: Object is moved and sized with the cells.

This means that if a `CheckBox` has its `Placement` property set as `xlFreeFloating` it will not move with the cell when the rows above it are deleted, as such this `CheckBox` will no longer be at the row intended. For this reason, before deleting any row we need to ensure the `Placement` property of all `CheckBoxes` is not `xlFreeFloating`.

Also as one row may contain more than one `CheckBox` we need to first create a range with all the rows to be deleted, then delete the `CheckBoxes` and finally delete the corresponding `Rows`

This procedure takes care of all the above:

Sub Shp_CheckBoxAndRow_Delete()
Dim ChkBox As CheckBox
Dim rRow As Range, rRowsDel As Range

```
Rem Set CheckBoxes Placement Property
For Each ChkBox In ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes
    ChkBox.Placement = xlMove
Next

Rem Set CheckBoxes Rows
For Each ChkBox In ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes

    Rem Set CheckBox Row
    'Set rRow = Range(ChkBox.TopLeftCell, ChkBox.BottomRightCell).EntireRow
    Set rRow = ChkBox.TopLeftCell.EntireRow
    rRow.Select: Stop
    rRow.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0): Stop

    Rem Join CheckBoxes Rows
    If rRowsDel Is Nothing Then
        Set rRowsDel = rRow
    Else
        Set rRowsDel = Union(rRowsDel, rRow)
    End If

Next

Rem Delete CheckBoxes
For Each ChkBox In ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes
    ChkBox.Delete
Next

Rem Delete CheckBoxes Rows
rRowsDel.Delete

End Sub
```