# I have an enormous Excel file with hundreds of checkboxes - what can I do?

Tags: excel, forms, checkbox, openpyxl, xlsx

One of our former colleagues created a big Excel with many items and multiple checkboxes (kind of a checklist), one for each item, even some of them have multiple checkboxes, grouped visually with merging cells, formats etc. but nothing standard.

The issue comes when, now, we need to manipulate that file, we need to delete some tables, because we need to adapt that Excel and share it with other employees that do not need to know the other part of the document, but this would be done dynamically, let's say that the document that we already have it's the base and from that one many will be derived each of one with a slightly different content.

The issue comes when we try to manipulate that file, there is no way to keep that checkboxes working outside that document. We have tried using openpyxl with Python we manage to copy everything except for the checkboxes, we have tried exporting the file to html and managing and editing that file, but the checkboxes are exported as images and obviously not working.

We run out of ideas and we do not know which approach would let us do what we are looking for.

I would like to point that redoing the file would not be an option, we are talking about thousands of items and that would be too time consuming. We know that doing this as an Excel have been a mistake but now it is too late to change it :_)

Thank you for your time and help, really appreciate it.

Comment: Use `win32com`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I already read about that choice but, correct me if I am wrong, that’s Windows only and we are not sure that will be the case, so we did not want to limit to that. Maybe where the Excel wil be consumed yes, but not where it would be “produced”. But thank you for your amswer!

Comment: Then you're likely out of luck, if you're using Python. Or you can contribute to the `openpyxl` library so that it supports  checkboxes.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Openpyxl 3.2 will provide better support for some of this stuff. But, as with all things open source, there is no fixed release schedule.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of trying two things:

1. If your original data is properly formatted as table/tables, you could try 'extracting' the information you need in separate files with PowerQuery; this would bring only the data
2. Make a copy of the file/sheets in a separate document; then remove the checkboxes programmatically; and finally make the adjustments to the data

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Sorry if I did not explained myself properly, my first question, but I want to keep the checkboxes. The document is kind of a checklist and I would like to preserver that checkboxes in the HTML or Markdown or whatever filetype I am able to extract it to.

And regarding PowerQuery I took a look but I did not find any related info about the checkboxes. Would you mind sharing something about it?

Thank you for your information!

Comment: You are right that PowerQuery does not allow keeping the checkboxes.

As you need to preserve the checkboxes, I would then suggest this:

Make a copy of the file/sheets in a separate document; then remove the unwanted rows from the list, making sure to also delete checkboxes on each of these rows. This would then leave a restricted list with checkboxes.

To get rid of the checkboxes you could try to use the ideas from this post:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33949944/delete-checkboxes-in-the-active-row-and-delete-the-entire-row